# Expandable/Collapsable TableView with Custom Cell for FAQs

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I wanted to implement **expandable/collapsable** `UITableView` with **Custom** `UITableViewCell` that adjusts its side according to the question/answer text. I have tried with different methods but none of it worked as I desire. If there is anyone who has implemented the same thing then kindly share the project link or let me know how it's done. Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. I am sharing the screenshot of what I wanted.[image]

Here's what I have tried. When I scroll the table view, it adds extra spaces between the cells and also messed up the UITextView.

```
enter code here

// Mark: Table View Delegate Methods

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let questionTextView = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 265.0, height: 30))
    let answerTextView = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 265.0, height: 30))

    questionTextView.text = questionStringArray[indexPath.row]
    answerTextView.text = answerStringArray[indexPath.row]

    Common.adjustUITextViewHeight(questionTextView)
    Common.adjustUITextViewHeight(answerTextView)

    let cellHeightExpanded:CGFloat = CGFloat(3 + Double(questionTextView.frame.size.height) + 5 + Double(answerTextView.frame.size.height) + 10)
    let cellHeightCollapsed:CGFloat = CGFloat(3 + Double(questionTextView.frame.size.height) + 5)

    if (indexPath.row == selectedQuestion)
    {
        return cellHeightExpanded
    }
    else
    {
        return cellHeightCollapsed
    }
}

// number of rows in table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

   return 5
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FAQsCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    cell.tvQuestion.text = questionStringArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.tvAnswer.text = answerStringArray[indexPath.row]

    Common.adjustUITextViewHeight(cell.tvQuestion)
    Common.adjustUITextViewHeight(cell.tvAnswer)

    cell.tvAnswer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: cell.tvAnswer.frame.origin.x, y : cell.tvQuestion.frame.origin.y + cell.tvQuestion.frame.size.height), size: CGSize(width: cell.tvAnswer.frame.size.width, height: cell.tvAnswer.frame.size.height))

    if indexPath.row == selectedQuestion {

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.okapiCellGrayColorForPendingAppLevel()
        cell.tvQuestion.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.tvAnswer.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
    else {

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.tvQuestion.textColor = UIColor.blue_grey_700()
        cell.tvAnswer.textColor = UIColor.blue_grey_700()
    }

    return cell
}

// method to run when table view cell is tapped
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selectedQuestion = indexPath.row
    faqsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/younatics/ExpandableCell/

Comment: Show the code you've tried

Comment: *"but none of it worked as I desire"* -- you need to explain what you've tried, and ***how*** it doesn't work as you desire.

Comment: I have created a custom cell and was adjusting its size in heightForRowAtIndex.
For that, I have written a method that increases the size of textview according to the text and after adjusting the textview size I was setting the frame of the cell.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for replying. I have updated my question and added the code. Kindly let me know if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: @RajeshKumar R Thanks for replying. I have updated my question and added the code. Kindly let me know if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: @Naqi - creating new text views for "measurement" purposes is a bad idea. Are you using `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` for a reason?

Comment: @DonMag yes its because I have a method that adjusts UITextView size according to the text. I couldn't find a method to do the same thing with the UILabel. 
Is there any way to adjust the size of the control that works similar to Android's wrap content?

Comment: @Naqi - there are numerous different approaches to this... unfortunately, what you're doing has far too many issues to correct via an answer here. For one, you should definitely be using auto-layout instead of calculating sizes. I'd suggest reviewing various examples, find one similar to what you are trying to do, and then work on modifying it to suit your needs. I have a Expand / Collapse example here (based on your image) that may get you on your way: https://github.com/DonMag/ExpandCollapse

Answer (score 0):

Add a vertical stackview in the custom cell and show/hide answer based on selected cell

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var questions = [(question:String,answer:String)]()
    var selectedQuestion = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questions = [(question:"Question 1",answer:"Answer 1"),(question:"Question 2",answer:"Answer 2"),
                    (question:"Question 3",answer:"Answer 3"),(question:"Question 4",answer:"Answer 4"),
                    (question:"Question 5",answer:"Answer 5")]
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        tableView.register(FAQsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "FAQsCell")
    }
}
extension ViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return questions.count
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQsCell") as! FAQsCell
        cell.questionLbl.text = questions[indexPath.row].question
        cell.answerLbl.text = questions[indexPath.row].answer
        if indexPath.row == selectedQuestion {
            cell.backgroundColor = .groupTableViewBackground
            cell.dropDownImgView.image = //upimage
            cell.answerView.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = .white
            cell.dropDownImgView.image = //downimage
            cell.answerView.isHidden = true
        }

        return cell
    }
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedQuestion = indexPath.row
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
class FAQsCell: UITableViewCell {

    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let questionLbl = UILabel()
    let dropDownImgView = UIImageView()
    let answerView = UIView()
    let answerLbl = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {

        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.spacing = 5
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(stackView)

        let questionView = UIView()
        questionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        questionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(questionView)

        questionLbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        questionLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        questionView.addSubview(questionLbl)

        dropDownImgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        dropDownImgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        questionView.addSubview(dropDownImgView)

        answerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        answerView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 35).isActive = true
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(answerView)

        answerLbl.numberOfLines = 0
        answerLbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        answerLbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        answerLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        answerView.addSubview(answerLbl)

        questionView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(10)-[questionLbl]-(10)-[dropDownImgView(25)]-(10@999)-|", options: [.alignAllCenterY], metrics: nil, views: ["questionLbl":questionLbl, "dropDownImgView": dropDownImgView]))
        dropDownImgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dropDownImgView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        questionView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(5)-[questionLbl(25)]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["questionLbl":questionLbl]))

        answerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(10)-[answerLbl]-(10)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["answerLbl":answerLbl]))
        answerView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(5)-[answerLbl(>=25)]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["answerLbl":answerLbl]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(5)-[stackView]-(5@999)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["stackView":stackView]))
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-(5)-[stackView]-(5)-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["stackView":stackView]))
    }
}
```

Comment: `reloadData` won't make a nice animation. The best solution would be entirely without reloading cells. That is, change the UI of an existing cell and update the heights in table (using `beginUpdates` & `endUpdates`).

Comment: @Sulthan I think getting the UI of the cell in `didSelectRowAt' and updating isn't good. Should I override selected method of cell?

Answer (score -2):

you can achieve through constraint.

give title and description constraint to bottom to superview.

after that change priority of constraint accordingly.

let me know if you want to understand through imagee.

Comment: Yes please share some images. That would be really helpful.